# Segmentation fault occuring in C but empty case is handled

Tags: c

I am trying to create a sorted linked_list repository in the most efficient way possible in C. The linked list will store data records that contain a "key" and a "data" value. The linked list should keep the records sorted by key. An example linked list would look like {1, 5}, {3, 8}, {4, 7}. The linked list keeps the records sorted by key.

I have a function called "invert" which adds a value to the list only if a record with the same key value does not already exist in the list. If the key is found in the list, it should remove the record. I already have functional code for all of this, but now I'm trying to make it more efficient, so I modified my code in order to reduce the number of iterations of the program. For some reason though, in my new code, I'm getting a segmentation fault. Furthermore, when I added print statements to debug, the print statements would not print unless I added the newline character to the end of the statements. Here is the code:

```
    node *pnode;
    printf("made pnode\n");
    node *delTemp;
    printf("made delTemp\n");
    node *travTemp;
    printf("made travTemp\n");

    travTemp = &sentinel; //sentinel is an empty node that is always
    // present in the linked list but is not an actual record. It is just there
    // to make insert and deletion easier

    while((travTemp->next)!=NULL && (travTemp->next->key)<key){
        printf("inside while loop\n");

        travTemp = travTemp->next;

    }

    if((travTemp->next->key)==key){
       printf("deleting\n");
       delTemp = travTemp->next;
       travTemp->next = delTemp->next;
       free(delTemp);
       return 0;
    }
    printf("outside while loop \n");
    pnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    pnode->data = data;
    pnode->key = key;
    pnode->next = travTemp->next;
    travTemp->next = pnode;
    return 1;
```

For some reason, neither "inside while loop" nor "outside while loop" will print. I wrote a quick if statement to see whether travTemp->next is null, which it should be at the beginning of the program. However, in that case, it should still print "outside while loop" shouldn't it? I am very confused as to where the segmentation fault is occurring. Thanks in advance for any help. Also, does anyone have any explanation as to why the print statements in the very beginning of the code would not print out unless I added "\n" to it?

Also, sentinel is defined as follows:

```
    node sentinel;
    void Repository_init(){
       sentinel.data = -1;
       sentinel.next = NULL;
       sentinel.key = -1;
    }
```

Repository_init() is called in main() without a problem.

EDIT:
I used a debugger and found that the seg fault is coming in at the statement "if ((travTemp->next->key)==key)". I can understand why this would occur at the start of the program, but I'm not sure how to overcome that. Putting an if statement around that if statement to check if travTemp is not NULL seems redundant.

Comment: How is `sentinel` defined (show the code for it)? That would be a key piece of information.

Comment: A debugger would answer this question for you in minutes.

Comment: `if((travTemp->next->key)==key){` maybe `travTemp->next` is `NULL`.

Comment: Right, it is. But the problem is overcoming that in the way I wrote my code since ideally my code should handle all special cases.

Comment: _I added "\n" to it?_ it may do to buffer flush at the timing of output a newline.

Comment: `while((travTemp->next)!=NULL && (travTemp->next->key)<key){`  If the loop is completed under the conditions of the first half portion.

Comment: This works. I was trying to find a better way to write it but I guess this is the best way at the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation fault is occuring due to

```
if((travTemp->next->key)==key){
```

when

```
travTemp->next == NULL
```

In this case both prints inside while loop and outside while will not be printed.